# How to access an item endpoint without login token in apiato php?

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code, apiato

I have been working on invoice system which I need to add each invoice with a QR generated by a system which when we print invoice as hard copy we can just scan the QR and access the preview page of that invoice (id). I am using apiato and every time I access the endpoint I need to login to get auth token. But as for customer they don't need to login to see the preview, just to see the invoice before paying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ex: 

Route::get('invoices', [Controller::class, 'getAllInvoices'])
    ->name('')
    ->middleware(['auth:api']);

    just delete ->middleware(['auth:api']);

    Route::get('invoices', [Controller::class, 'getAllInvoices'])
    ->name('');
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:
remove auth:api from route middleware in path: routes/api.php

```
// Users
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
      Route::apiResource('/users', Api\UsersController::class);
      });
// or:    
    Route::group( function () {
      Route::apiResource('/users', Api\UsersController::class);
      });

// another example:
Route::apiResource('api/show-invoice', [InvoiceController::class, 'show.invoice']);
```

Comment: I have tried, but seems like it doesn't work, it redirects to the login page